# await message.awaitReaction with an async filter isn't awaited

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, discord.js

Why is my console logging "Finished" before "Started" ?
Why can't I await message.awaitReactions(); ?

```
const filter = async /*It is here for no reason but without it does not work neither*/ (reaction, user) => {
  if (user.id == players[p].user.id && aEmojis.indexOf(reaction.emoji.name) != -1) {
     console.log("Started");
     attackedIndex = aEmojis[aEmojis.indexOf(reaction.emoji.name)+1];
     message.delete();
     return true;
  }
  return false;
};


await message.awaitReactions(filter, {max: 1});
console.log("Finished");
```

Comment: your awaitReactions must return a promise. The async for your filter has no sense.

Comment: `async` function without `await` in it == code smell.

Comment: I tried without the await too

Answer (score 0):

`await` works in async functions

```
  (async function() {
  const filter = async (reaction, user) => {
  if (user.id == players[p].user.id && aEmojis.indexOf(reaction.emoji.name) != -1) {
     console.log("Started");
     attackedIndex = aEmojis[aEmojis.indexOf(reaction.emoji.name)+1];
     message.delete();
     return true;
  }
  return false;
  };


  await message.awaitReactions(filter, {max: 1});
  console.log("Finished");
  })();
```

Comment: thanks you for the help, I tried with that now and it still does not work, I will continue investigating looks like my case is weird